# Python Prime Generator

Tags: python, generator, primes

Yes, I know there are a ton of these out there, and my question has probably already been answered somewhere I have not seen. However, I am still having difficulty and am unsure as to what to do.

```
maximum_range = int(input('How big do you want the range?'));
i = 3;
checkPrime = True;
while (i <= maximum_range):
    y = 2;
    print('i {}'.format(i))
    print('y {}'.format(y))
    halfI = int((i/2)+ 1)
    checkPrime = False;
    while (y <= halfI & checkPrime):
        y += 1
        if (i%y == 0):
            print('{} is not prime because it is divisible by' .format(i))
            checkPrime = False;
    i += 2
    if (checkPrime & y == halfI):
        print('{}s is prime' .format(i))   
    checkPrime = True;
```

The problem is the nested iteration does not work, it reaches 'here 1', and that's it. I have also printed y and i- which print the correct values, yet it seems to not do anything.

Many thanks to those helping- please be patient, I much prefer Javascript.

Comment: You didn't say what the *difficulty* is, you haven't asked a question, you haven't described how it is unsatisfactory.  Have you tried printing variables, comparison results, and other things at strategic locations to see what might be happening?

Comment: what exactly is the difficulty you are having? Does this code work? or you want it to produce something else?

Comment: Python does not require semicolons at the end of statements, Python coders reading that may find it annoying and to top it off you have scattered them around randomly on a subset of statements.  That's a style comment, not your problem.

Comment: Welcome to SO, Please take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page. As is your question is a little too broad. Focus on one way your code may be misbehaving and ask about that. If you find a solution to that question and there is still a problem, try to figure it out then ask a new question about that.

Comment: As written, your inner loop will never run - is that loop's comparison behaving the way you thought t would? ; it looks like you tried to optimize by only searching half the search space (with `halfI`)  maybe simplify and remove all that logic and see if it will work, testing with small values of `maximum_range `.

Answer (score 0):

You have missunderstand python's operators:

As pointed out here: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#binary-bitwise-operations

> The operator & yields the bitwise AND of its arguments, which must be integers.

What you should use is the "and" logical operator.

Another thing that you should care is about operator precedence: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence

About the logic of your code, as long as you discover new prime numbers you can use them to divide (perform modulus operation) too much faster (fewer steps), because every number can decompose in a prime factors product. I dont give you an example, because i don't know excatly what do you want to achieve, if you give an example of what do you need I can make it.